# Validate DOM tree / find unclosed tags offline

Tags: html, web-development

Are there any simple tool to use for finding unclosed tags? Like a missing , wrong spelled , /div> and so on?

W3C distributing some offline installations but I'm not using Apache and any kind of GNU systems for my development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) tool attempts to fix missing or mismatched tags, badly nested tags, and more. The 'offline' version is [available here.](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) Online versions are available from [Infohound](http://infohound.net/tidy/) and the [W3C.](http://services.w3.org/tidy/tidy)